# Hiding items from front page if in your cart

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, e-commerce

I'm very shaky with django and Python, but I'm making a second hand ecommerce site (like ebay), and I'm struggling to do something that I'm sure is simple:

If an item has been added to your cart, and you continue browsing, I don't want them to be able to see this item. This is because each item is unique, so seeing it again could mean adding it again, which wouldn't make sense!

So far, I've been able to hide a users own items, but I just can't get my head around this part.

Here's my code:

the views.py for items:

```
def get_items(request):
    """Create a view that will return a list of all items and render them
    to the 'items.html' template"""
    user = request.user
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        items = Item.objects.exclude(owner=user).filter(date_added__lte=timezone.now
            ()).order_by('-date_added')
    else:
        items = Item.objects.filter(date_added__lte=timezone.now
            ()).order_by('-date_added')
    return render(request, "items.html", {"items" : items, "profile": user})
```

The cart views.py

```
def view_cart(request):
    """
    A view to render cart contents
    """
    return render(request, "cart.html")

def add_to_cart(request, id):
    """
    A view to add item to cart
    """
    cart = request.session.get('cart', [])
    if id in cart:
        cart[id] = int(cart[id])
        print("already in list - this will not add another")
    else:
        cart[id] = cart.get(id)
        print("not Found")

    request.session['cart'] = cart

return redirect(reverse('view_cart'))
```

Let me know if you need anything else, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If an item gets an user object when it goes to the cart, maybe the __isnull works for you:

```
items = Item.objects.exclude(owner__isnull=False).filter(date_added__lte=timezone.now
            ()).order_by('-date_added')
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, the owner=user bit makes sure you can't see your own uploaded items when browsing, I need then to also hide any items in your cart

Answer (score 0):

You can query the cart and get id's of products from the cart and then use them in exclude like this.

```
cart_products = ["1", "56"] #<--  Create a list of id'd of products in your user's cart and use it as a variable or directly in query.
```

Refer **[__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut)** method used to make pk lookup.

```
items = Item.objects.exclude(owner=user, id__in=cart_products).filter(date_added__lte=timezone.now
        ()).order_by('-date_added')
```